# Digital Post-Its on Browser Tabs?

Tags: firefox, notes

I work with a lot of tabs in firefox, since in my context I often need to wait several minutes until I can work further in this browser tab.

It would be very cool if I could post a digital post-it note on firefox tabs to remind my what the next action in this tab is.

I searched here https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/tag/postit. But these solution don't help me. I just want simple notes per tab and if I close the tab the note gets deleted, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one seems to have a solution, I post my current solution here:

I add a comment after the URL.

Example

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/550548/digital-post-its-on-browser-tabs###check for new comments
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a beta addon called [tabcandy](http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/tabcandy/) which may be what you want:

Comment: What does tabcandy provide that is not provided by tab groups? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tab-groups-organize-tabs